# Certificate authority SSL using AWS load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, certificate-authority

I need to get an 'authority certified' SSL certificate for services being supplied by an AWS classic-load-balancer.

The concern is; normally these certificates are authenticated against an IP address. However, AWS load-balancers do not have consistent IP addresses...they randomly change - and as far as I know, you cannot ASSIGN a fixed IP to an AWS load balancer.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: *normally these certificates are authenticated against an IP address.*  No, they aren't.  SSL certificates are issued against the hostname of the service, such as `www.example.com`.  The IP address is not important.  Perhaps you are confused by this: In the days before SNI, for web servers with web multiple sites, SSL certs were mapped to static IP addresses on web servers... but this had nothing to do with the cert, directly --
this was done so that the server knew which domain was being accessed so that the correct cert for that site would be returned to the client.

Comment: OK. Good to know. Thanks! That may be the solution then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AWS Certificate Manager to request a 'free' trusted certificate for use with AWS services like the AWS Load Balancer

https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ssl-server-cert.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any idea if this would satisfy the Apple Store's new requirements for SSL on the server-side?

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about that